# Boolean Error in Java converted to String

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

```
Main.java:138: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String
            if(formatString(positions[index].equalsIgnoreCase(formatString(position))))
                                                             ^
Main.java:160: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String
            if(formatString(players[index].equalsIgnoreCase(formatString(player))))
```

Above are the errors. I would like to know where the boolean changes to String.

formatString() is a method
positions[] is an Array of String

```
 /**
 * Method that finds the index of player by using the position
 *
 * @param   position    The position of the baseball player
 * @return     The index of the player at a certain position
 */
public int findIndex(String position)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(index < positions.length)
    {
        if(formatString(positions[index].equalsIgnoreCase(formatString(position))))
        {
            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method that finds the player position by finding the name
 *
 * @param   player  The namee of the player
 * @return     The position that matches the players name
 */
public String findPlayerPosition(String player)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(index < players.length)
    {
        if(formatString(players[index].equalsIgnoreCase(formatString(player))))
        {
            return positions[index];
        }
        else
        {
            return "NONE";
        }
    }
}
```

The formatString() Method

```
public String formatString(String oldString)
        {
             return (oldString.equals("") ? oldString : (oldString.trim()).toUpperCase());
        }
```

The formatString() Method does the trim() and uppercase() to a string passed through the parameter.

Comment: Show `formatString`. It seems to be returning a bool.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here, in the condition of your `if` statement:

```java
if(formatString(positions[index].equalsIgnoreCase(formatString(position)))
```

Let's expand this slightly:

```java
final boolean equivalent = positions[index].equalsIgnoreCase(formatString(position));
final boolean condition = formatString(equivalent);
if (condition) {
    // ...
}
```

Now, `position` is a `String`, `formatString` accepts and returns a `String`, `positions[index]` is a `String`, and `equalsIgnoreCase` compares `String`s. So, the first line is fine.

The second line, however... in the expanded form, it's clear that you're trying to call `formatString` with a `boolean`. We know it's supposed to accept a `String`, so that's the error that's being reported. There's another issue, though - `formatString` *returns* a `String`, but since you're using it as the condition of an `if` statement, it has to be a `boolean`.

I think dropping the outer call to `formatString` would sort out your issue. As an aside, the ternary operator inside `formatString` is unnecessary, since  "".trim().equals(""). Er, and since you're using `equalsIgnoreCase`, the `toUpperCase` in `formatString` is also redundant, so why not just

```java
if (positions[index].equalsIgnoreCase(position))
```

?

*Update*: `formatString` was not provided originally. This answer has been rewritten now that it has been.

Comment: Added the formatString() method.
Mayeb the header has the issue?

Comment: @ParthSPatel I've rewritten the answer with this new information.